# Need to put text over images in a table

Tags: html, css, text, dreamweaver

I made a webpage in Photoshop CS4, sliced it up, threw it in a table in Dreamweaver CS4. http://www.themegan.info/lab4/index.htm (rough start, I know) Now, how do I go about putting text on top of the images?  Do I use CSS?  I am just confused at this point.

Comment: As I hope you've guessed, there's a little more to creating websites than using Photoshop slices. You need to learn how to create proper HTML/CSS, from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

```
<td style="position:relative;">
    <img src="..." style="position:absolute;z-index:1;" />
    <div style="z-index:2;position:relative;">your text goes here</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Yeah, should have researched more beforehand.  I used absolute positioning.  Not sure how I didn't think of it before.  Thanks.

Comment: @Megan, if this answered your question, please click the checkmark beside the question. If this didn't answer your question, click the checkmark near the one that did! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the images as backgrounds of your layout "parts" through css. I.e.

html:

```
<div id="content">...text...</div>
```

css:

```
#content{
    background:url(..imgurl..) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want your users to interact with the image (i.e. the navigation menu images) you should use the css background-image property to make your design elements go to the background. Example:

```
td#sidebar { background-image:sidebarimg.jpg no-repeat; }
```

Then whatever text you put into your td element will automatically be on top of the image. This is especially important because it means a lot less upkeep will be required in maintaining your site.